# Visualization of k-cores using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to plot the k-cores of a graph in a nice visualization which can illustrate the different k-core values (for instance, https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Illustration-of-the-k-core-decomposition-Here-k-max-3_fig1_326621799).
A sample of dataset is the following:

```
Node Target Label
A      F      1
A      B      1
A      N      1
B      A      0
B      F      0 
C      F      1
A      V      1
D      S      0
D      E      0
F      A      1
F      B      1
F      G      1
G      E      0
E      W      0
```

To identify the nodes with at least degree k I am using the following piece of code:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Node', 'Target')

kcore=nx.k_core(G)

plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Full')
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)


plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Main')
nx.draw(kcore,with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to figure it out, for example using a loop across k values or assigning different colors depending on the value of k...

Any help or tips would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict

# create dataframe
# df = ...

# build graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Node', 'Target')

# build a dictionary of k-level with the list of nodes
kcores = defaultdict(list)
for n, k in nx.core_number(G).items():
    kcores[k].append(n)

# compute position of each node with shell layout
pos = nx.layout.shell_layout(G, list(kcores.values()))
colors = {1: 'red', 2: 'green'}  # need to be improved, for demo

# draw nodes, edges and labels
for kcore, nodes in kcores.items():
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_color=colors[kcore])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=0.2)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

[image: networkx]

Comment: Hi Corralien, yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: I am also trying to do the same thing but I don't have Label. Can anyone tell me how I can get label. So, when I ran the above code, this line [nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_color=colors[kcore])] gave the KeyError: 150. This is the first time I am doing K-core decomposition, so I don't have any idea how I solve this problem.

Comment: @PiyushGhasiya. What is the length of colors and kcores?

Comment: @Corralien Thank you for your reply. Actually to tell you the truth I have no idea about any of the parameters. I just tried your code (with no changes) on my dataset. Can you please suggest any tutorial to understand your code or k-core decomposition? Would it be alright if I ask a separate question? But I am also confused about how should I frame my question so that I can get replies.

Comment: In this problem, I hardcoded the color for each k-core becasuse I know there are 2 k-cores only. Try: `colors = {k: f"#{c[0]:02x}{c[1]:02x}{c[2]:02x}" for k, c in zip(kcores, np.random.randint(0, 256, (len(kcores), 3)))}`. Follow the tutorial in the question.

Comment: @Corralien thank you so much, it worked. I was able to produce a plot.